# Compilation with GTK in Code::Blocks undefined reference to `gdk_cairo_create'

Tags: windows, gtk, codeblocks, undefined-reference, gtk2

After a serious system crash, I had to reinstall everything (Windows 10), including Code::Blocks (version 16.01) to develop my code using the GTK+2 library. I ended up with a strange situation that I can't solve.

Some of my programs are compiling correctly, while others don't. Here is a copy of the build log output for an example that does not compile correctly:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\lib" -o bin\Debug\trajecto.exe obj\Debug\main.o   -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\lib\cairo.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\lib\libpangocairo-1.0.dll.a"
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `on_expose_event_trajet':
D:/calcul C/essai gtk/essai gtk/trajecto/main.c:804: undefined reference to `gdk_cairo_create'
D:/calcul C/essai gtk/essai gtk/trajecto/main.c:805: undefined reference to `gdk_cairo_create'
D:/calcul C/essai gtk/essai gtk/trajecto/main.c:806: undefined reference to `gdk_cairo_create'
D:/calcul C/essai gtk/essai gtk/trajecto/main.c:807: undefined reference to `gdk_cairo_create'
D:/calcul C/essai gtk/essai gtk/trajecto/main.c:890: undefined reference to `gdk_cairo_create'
obj\Debug\main.o:D:/calcul C/essai gtk/essai gtk/trajecto/main.c:939: more undefined references to `gdk_cairo_create' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
7 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

And here is what I get for a program that compiles correctly (still using gdk_cairo_create()):

```
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -mms-bitfields -g -Wall -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\include\gtk-2.0" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\include\cairo" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\include\gdk" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\include\glib-2.0" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\lib\glib-2.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\include\pango-1.0" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\lib\gtk-2.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\include\atk-1.0" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\include\gdk-pixbuf-2.0" -c "D:\calcul C\essai gtk\essai gtk\Michal\main.c" -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\lib" -o bin\Debug\ehpad.exe obj\Debug\main.o   -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\lib\pango-1.0.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\lib\gdk-win32-2.0.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\lib\cairo.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\lib\libpangocairo-1.0.dll.a"
Output file is bin\Debug\ehpad.exe with size 69.91 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

There are differences but how can I know (and understand) where is the problem? I've tried a lot of different things. The libraries included in the linker options are the same for both on these examples (cairo.lib and libpangocairo-1.0.dll.a).

I've found in different places on the web that the order of arguments on the compilation line can matter, but I do not see in Code::Blocks how this can be changed.

This is driving me crazy, and I would be very thankful if someone can give me a hint on that.

Thanks in advance and cheers, Eric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs tell you the error you have is a link error, so it's clear that you need to check the differences between the link parameters.

I first copy/pasted the link commands you gave in 2 different files. Then used a diff tool that can tell what's different within a single line: [meld](http://meldmerge.org/). The result is that you're missing some libraries, which are not given to the linker in your non-working setup.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\lib\pango-1.0.lib"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\gtk\lib\gdk-win32-2.0.lib"
```

`gdk_cairo_create` belongs to `gdk`. Since you're using the win32 backend, it exists in `gdk-win32-2.0.lib` so the linker complains rightfully as you're not linking with it.

However, all these parameters should normally be sorted out by [calls to `pkg-config`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk-compiling.html) in your linker options. This avoids forgetting dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem. I've added these two libraries to the linker and it works now. Thanks! What surprises me is that I've already seen these two libraries missing and I already tried that before and it did not work. I must have make some mistakes.. The other thing that surprises me is that, indeed, these two libraries should have been already there. Anyhow, thanks so much for helping me in solving this issue, that drove me crazy for a couple of weeks. Cheers, Eric.